# iOS - Keep input keyboard of TextField state when change to different TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift-keyboard

I have 10 TextFields, each TextField is a character (it can be numbers or letters). Each TextField will have difference appearance, 10 fields will build to a 10 characters code.

Every time the user input a character into the field, I will switch focus to the next field to ensure smooth input. But each time I switch to the next view, the keyboard will return to its original state (ex: in the previous field I toggle to the numeric keypad to enter (numbers), the next field will reset to normal (letters)) . Is there a way to detect the state of the keyboard before changing the field and manually set it?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use one `UITextField` or create custom [InputView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputview). For example, you can look at [SGDigitTextField](https://github.com/sonifex/SGDigitTextField/blob/master/SGDigitTextField/Classes/SGDigitTextField.swift) or [SGCodeTextField](https://github.com/grigorievs/SGCodeTextField/blob/master/Sources/SGCodeTextField/SGCodeTextField.swift).
Main idea is using a hidden UITextView to get input and draw a inputted text with labels.